# Does Mitochondrial Eve suggest evolutionary fitness of her DNA?

Tags: distributions

As background Mitochondrial Eve is the name give to our common ancestor about 200,000 years. I was asking about this in the biology stack exchange, but it seems like kind of a math question.

Mitochondrial DNA is passed from mother to daughter. A women could say all of her daughters would have her Mitochondrial dna.  Also, all of her daughters' daughters would have her Mitochondrial dna.  However, her son's daughter's would not have her Mitochondrial dna.  (Her son married some other women, and their children would have that women's Mitochondrial  dna.)

Given this framework, assuming no evolutionary forces, fitness of one DNA over another, should the descendants end up with a random Mitochondrial dna?  If you had a thousand women, should dna of the descendants thousand of years later be equally distributed in groups that represent the Mitochondrial descendants of each women?

Thanks

Edit --

I changed the wording a bit.  Basically, I think the initial population should be equally represented in final population, if there is no selection bias.

Comment: FYI, my idea was that since her Mitochondrial dna survived it suggested a biased, none random system.

Comment: The alternative of random reproduction is a [Galton–Watson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process) where if the total population is stable, the expected number of original mitochondrial ancestors would decrease towards $1$ over time

Comment: Rather than asking about "randomly distributed," which is a given (in any reasonable model the process of producing descendants will be randomized), you should be inquiring concerning what the resulting distribution is.  The answer depends on your probability model for reproduction and mating.  One thing that can be said generally is that starting with $M$ distinct genotypes in $M$ otherwise equivalent mothers, the *expected fraction* in the population at any generation endowed with any specified genotype is $1/M.$ But that can arise even when some genotypes disappear from the population.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I think the population would be divided into M basically equal groups.  However, the real life results are that there is one group.

Comment: That said, people use Galton-Watson to argue that the other populations would be removed.

Comment: I tried in the final sentence to be clear: the *expectation* is $1/M,$ but that does not mean that *in any particular instance* there will be $M$ nearly equal groups! Indeed, one possibility under some models is that very rapidly all but on genotype completely dies out.  (But the initial equality of circumstances implies *every* genotype is equally likely to die out.) This points out how important it is to (a) frame the question appropriately and (b) supply specifics about the model you have in mind.

Comment: @whuber Do you think that the results are caused by some sort of evolutionary bias?  Or you think hypothetically if all the women of that time were completely equal we would still normally just end up with one mitochondrial ancestor.

Comment: It would strain credulity to suppose that not one of your thousand women would be stomped on by a woolly mammoth or happen to bear only sons, regardless of her mitochondrial genome: thinning of the maternal lineages by time and chance alone would be inevitable. The existence of a mitochondrial Eve suggests nothing about the strength of selection; that she lived 200,000 years ago, & not 2,000 or 2,000,000 years ago, doubtless does. But as @whuber says, you need to explain what probability model you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

**The qualitative evolution of such a population depends on the dynamics of reproduction.  Let's look at some of the possibilities.**

Rather than offer a mathematical analysis, **I present some simulations** to *show* what can happen.  Although these make simplifying assumptions, they faithfully reflect the behavior of realistic systems.

We begin with a population of mothers (the males play no role, alas).  It is represented by a vector indexed by the distinct genotypes whose values count the numbers of each genotype in the population.  The initial population posited in the question therefore corresponds to the vector $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$ with one thousand ones: a thousand distinct genotypes.

**The simulation is simple.**  A "generational clock" ticks.  At each successive moment, each mother in the population is replaced by zero or more offspring of the same genotype according to a specified random distribution.

**What turns out to govern the general behavior of this population's evolution** are (a) the chance of dying with no offspring; (b) the chance of having a single child surviving to reproduce next time; and (c) the expected number of surviving children.  Clearly, when this expectation is less than $1,$ the population will die out (fairly steadily).  When this expectation is close to $1,$ the total population size will behave like a random walk and (therefore) will still eventually die out.  When the expectation exceeds $1,$ the population size ought to increase exponentially on average.

We are interested in the numbers of each genotype over time and the number of distinct genotypes.  I therefore plot these for each simulation, along with total population size.  To make the computation feasible for large populations, I limit the total population size by randomly (and uniformly) killing people off if necessary.  I also resort to an approximate sampling method (based on a Normal approximation to the distribution) once the numbers of any given genotype grow large.

**The figure below presents four scenarios.**  In all of them

- The initial population is one thousand distinct genotypes.
- Each mother can produce 0, 1, 2, or 3 surviving offspring.  The chances of each are given as a vector in the plot titles below.
- The simulation extends for 10,000 generations (at 20 years or so per human generation, that's 200,000 years).
- The growth rate per generation is 1.001 in each scenario.  Thus, the expected population size after 10,000 generations is approximately $1000 \exp((0.001)\times 10000),$ which is about 22 million.  I thin large generations to keep them below ten million.

The scenarios differ according to (a), the chance of dying with no offspring.  I have varied these from $0.4$ down to $0.001$ to provide a range of behaviors.

Rather than interpret these in detail, I leave it to you to consider anything that might interest you.  But I will point out two salient features:

1. It's practically inevitable, under any of these scenarios, that **the majority of genotypes will eventually disappear.**
2. The scenarios differ according to how many distinct genotypes persist after 10,000 generations.  Notice, in particular, that in the first scenario (with $0.4$ chance of each mother having no surviving offspring) 99.7% of the genotypes have disappeared rapidly.  (Starting with a smaller population, it's likely *all* will have died out.)
3. Among the surviving genotypes **there is a large variation in subpopulation size.**  Some genotypes remain rare while a few appear to dominate the population.
4. Nevertheless, because originally each genotype is identically situated -- they are all present in the same numbers and are subject to identical reproduction and thinning -- **every genotype has the same chance of surviving and each one has the same expected proportion of the population at any generation.**

**Therein lies the point of this simulation:** to show how *in any actual example of the evolution of a population, the characteristics of that population are likely to differ markedly from the expected values.*  That's not a paradox, because *the expectation is taken over all possible ways the population could have evolved* and therefore does not have to reflect any specific history.

**These insights are applicable to more than human populations.**  As an example, comparable simulations might help us understand financial markets: when we study the returns of an asset over time, with the intention of selecting something for an investment, we must bear in mind that *the existing assets only reflect the survivors.*  The stocks and bonds of defunct companies are no longer in the market.

[image: Panel of four rows of three plots each]

In all these plots, generation 0 is the initial population.

---

**The following `R` code produced these simulations** and is flexible enough to produce a wide variety of other simulations.  It defaults to an initial population of 100 which is evolved for 100 generations: the calculation will be almost instantaneous.  (The calculations for the figure, which required one thousand times this effort, took six minutes.)

It's worth pointing out that the heart of the code is truly short and simple: the tally of genotypes `x` in one generation is updated using a probability vector `prob` to the next generation by looping over the counts `m` and executing one line:

```R
sum(sample.int(length(probs), m, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) - 1)
```

`sample.int` draws the multinomial sample (effectively representing each individual among these `m` individuals) to find the number of offspring of each mother and, of course, `sum` adds them up.  The code simply repeats this in an outer loop while keeping track of any population properties of interest along the way.  Most of the code is devoted to plotting the results.

```R
next.generation <- function(x, probs) {
  # `x` tallies the genotypes;
  # `probs` gives the chances of each mother having 0, 1, ... daughters.
  sapply(x, \(m) {
    if (m <= 5 / min(probs[probs > 0])) {
      # Multinomial sampling
      sum(sample.int(length(probs), m, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) - 1)
    } else {
      # Normal approximation to the multinomial
      k <- 0:(length(probs) - 1)
      mu <- sum(k * probs)
      sigma <- sqrt(m * sum((k - mu)^2 * probs))
      pmax(0, round(rnorm(1, mu * m, sigma)))
    }
  })
}
thin <- function(x, n.max) {
  # The population tallied in `x` is randomly and uniformly reduced to
  # total approximately `n.max` individuals.
  lambda <- n.max / sum(x)
  if (lambda < 1) x <- rbinom(length(x), x, lambda)
  x
}
p_ <- function(x, y, rho = 0.001) {
  # Create a probability distribution with generational growth rate `1+rho` where
  # `x` = Pr(0 children) and `y` = Pr(1 children).  Only 0, 1, 2, or 3
  # children are possible.
  w <- rho + 2*x + y - 1
  z <- 1 - x - y - w
  probs <- c(x, y, z, w)
  if (any(probs < 0)) warning("No solution.")
  probs
}
p <- function(x, rho = 0.001) {
  # A special sort-of-symmetric case of `p_`.
  zapsmall(p_(x, 1 - 2*x, rho))
}
#
# Run some illustrative simulations.
#
Probs <- list(
  p(0.4),       # Genotypes rapidly die out -- and so does the population
  p(0.1),       # Usually a few are left after a 10,000 generations
  p(0.01),      # Several are left after 10,000 generations
  p(0.001)      # Many (30 - 40%) are left after 10,000 generations
)
# set.seed(17)
p.start <- rep(1, 1e2) # Initial population of `n.start[i]` individuals of genome `i`.
n.generations <- 1e2   # Maximum length of simulation
pop.max <- 1e7         # Limiting population size (approximately)

# pdf("CV.pdf", width = 10, height = 13) # For large simulations run in the background
par(mfrow = c(length(Probs), 3))
for (probs in Probs) {
  probs <- probs / sum(probs)
  stitle <- paste0("(", paste(signif(probs, 2), collapse = ", "), ")")
  # sum(probs * 0:(length(probs)-1)) # Growth rate per generation
  #
  # Run the simulation.
  #
  population <- p.start
  Simulation <- cbind(population,
                      sapply(seq_len(n.generations), \(g)
                             population <<- thin(next.generation(population, probs), pop.max)
                      ))
  #
  # Compute summaries by generation.
  #
  N <- colSums(Simulation)             # Population sizes by generation
  Simulation <- Simulation[, N > 0]    # Remove empty generations
  N <- N[N > 0]
  # -- The population proportions are jittered for plotting
  Proportions <- t(t(Simulation + rbeta(prod(dim(Simulation)), 3/2, 3/2) - 1/2) / N)
  Genotypes <- colSums(Simulation > 0) # Number of distinct genotypes per generation
  #
  # Plot the simulation.
  #
  plot(c(0, ncol(Proportions)-1), c(0, max(Proportions, na.rm = TRUE)), type = "n",
       main = paste("Proportions for", stitle),
       ylab = "Proportion", xlab = "Generation",
       family = "Informal")
  # -- Trace each genotype's proportion of the population over time, distinguishing
  # them by color.
  invisible(sapply(seq_len(nrow(Proportions)),
                   \(i) {
                     y <- Proportions[i, ]
                     j <- y > 0 & !is.na(y)
                     lines(which(j) - 1, y[j],
                           col = hsv(0.9 * i / nrow(Proportions), 1, 0.8, 0.5))
                   }))

  plot(seq_along(Genotypes) - 1, Genotypes, ylim = c(0, length(population)),
       main = paste("Genotypes for", stitle),
       ylab = "# Distinct Genotypes", xlab = "Generation",
       family = "Informal")

  plot(seq_along(N) - 1, N, log = if(min(N) == 0) "" else "y",
       main = paste("Population for", stitle),
       ylab = "Population Size", xlab = "Generation",
       family = "Informal")
}
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
# dev.off() # If outputting to pdf
```